# Database Design for application while in draft status

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing an application for a governmental entity that is responsible for registering and approving consulting firms. They have a long form that needs to be filled by the consulting firm(the applicant). The form contains a list of consultants who are working for the firm. They might be full-time or part-time consultants.  For designing the database for the applications the following entities are initially identified: Firm, Application, Registration,and Consultant. Of course, the application will be in a draft status before it's approved. Upon approval, a record will be entered for the firm in the Firm table, a record for each approved consultant will be entered in the consultant table, and a record in the registration table showing the registration date and ID. My question is how to hold the information of the application and its associated list of consultants while waiting approval?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe add a status field to the tables?!

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing @EhsanT commented.  Add a status field.  That field should be a foreign key to a status table, that contains the possible status values.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500 - Does that mean I will keep the data for the approved and under processing  firms and their consultants in the same table and just change the status? Some applications might be rejected as well - and some consultants can be approved and some can be rejected. For instance, an application for a firm that has 10 consultants can result in approving the firm and approving just 4 consultants out of the  10. Thanks!

Comment: In such a context, each application would be 1 line in the applications table.  Same for consultants.  The status decides what to do with each line in the table.